# Three coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following set of differential equations, I am trying to do it by the usual decoupling methods like adding the equations, subtracting etc which makes the process rather lengthy.Is there any other method, perhaps some transformation matrix which can simplify the problem.

\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2\lambda +V(r) & \frac{\alpha}{2}\partial_r & 0 \\
\alpha(\partial_r+\frac{1}{r}) & V(r) & \alpha(\partial_r+\frac{1}{r})\\
0 & -\frac{\alpha}{2}\partial_r & 2\lambda+ V(r)
\end{array} \right) \left (\begin{array}{c}
\phi_1(r)\\
\phi_2(r)\\
\phi_3(r)
\end{array} \right)=\epsilon
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\phi_1(r)\\
\phi_2(r)\\
\phi_3(r)
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for decoupling the equations, note that it is not through some transformation of the matrix. Rearranging your first and third equations gives

\begin{align}
\phi_1 &= \frac{1}{2 \lambda + \varepsilon - V(r)} \frac{\alpha}{2} \frac{d \phi_2}{d r}, \\
\phi_3 &= \frac{1}{2 \lambda -\varepsilon + V(r)} \frac{\alpha}{2} \frac{d \phi_2}{d r}.
\end{align}

And rearranging your second equation allows it to be written as 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dr} \big[ r(\phi_1 + \phi_3) \big] + \left( \frac{V(r) - \varepsilon}{\alpha} \right) r \phi_2 = 0.
\end{align}

Next I substitute the expressions given above for $\phi_1$ and $\phi_3$ into this equation, this yields the following second order ODE for the quantity $\phi_2(r)$

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dr} \left(r \beta(r) \frac{d \phi_2}{dr}  \right) + \left( \frac{V(r) - \varepsilon}{\alpha^2} \right) r \phi_2 = 0,
\end{align}

where the function $ \beta(r) := \dfrac{2 \lambda}{[2 \lambda + \varepsilon - V(r)][2 \lambda - \varepsilon + V(r)]}$ has been defined for convenience.

Comment: Hi, thanks for working out the equations, but you have missed a crucial point that $V$ is a function of $r$, $V(r)$ which in my case is $\frac{g}{r}$,  which implies that $\beta $ is not a constant.

Comment: I am expecting solutions of the form of confluent hypergeometric functions from intuition.

Comment: @vibhutibhushanjha oops! I completely forgot about this when I wrote the problem down. I shall update my answer, although the solution won't be as neat now. However, the equations will still be decoupled as asked in your OP.

Comment: No problem, I am thinking of a solution of the form $\phi=\rho^{\gamma-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{\rho}{2}}\Phi(\rho)$, where I have scaled $\rho=\epsilon r$, where $\gamma$ and $g$ are constants.

Comment: @vibhutibhushanjha: that sounds rather complicated! Good luck.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could suggest some workaround.

Comment: @vibhutibhushanjha, I cannot clearly see one. My thoughts were to were to write the denominator of $\beta$ as a difference of two squares and the make a change of independent variable $y \mapsto g/r - \varepsilon$. But the ODE is still has very nasty variable coefficients.